# I have a XGBoost model and I need to use it in an android app

Tags: python, android, model, kivy, xgboost

I want to create an android app that uses a XGBoost model. As I need to do signal processing and feature extraction, I thought that this requires me to do this part of code in python.

My question is, having this model (json) what is the best way to start developing the app? Should I do an entire python app using Kivy ? If so, does kivy support XGBoost?

Should I use chaquopy instead?

Is it better to use a REST API to my model?

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that Chaquopy does support [XGBoost version 1.1.1](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/xgboost/). It doesn't look like Kivy supports it, because it's not in their [list of recipes](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/develop/pythonforandroid/recipes).